# Can I get the last 4 digits of a regex credit card number?

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex pattern for an AMEX Credit Card format - (?<!\d)3[47][0-9]{13}(?!\d).  Is there a way to get the last 4 characters or digits?

I'm trying to mask a credit card in case a credit card format has been inserted in the form. So instead of credit card being inserted, it will be asked something like **** **** **** 1234

Comment: `cc.Substring(cc.Length-4);` ? Call me old fashioned, though it scares me that someone who is dealing with credit card numbers are asking questions like this on SO

Comment: Please provide a specific case and explain your needs. You can use [SubString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netcore-3.1) to intercept the string.

Comment: What if the credit card is within words?  For example...My card number is 340000000000009 and I have.  The last 4 will results to "have".

Answer (score 1):

It can be 16 digit credit card or more so you can match it using this regex or You can goto
[This Link](https://regex101.com/) and generate your own regex

```
Regex  (?i)^((\d+\s+?\d+\s+?\d+\s+?)(\d{4}))
```

In here accessing the Group2

```
                var Creditcardno= // Here put your credit card no
                string reg = @"(?i)^((\d+\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+)(\d{4})))";
                Regex r = new Regex(reg, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                Match m = r.Match(Creditcardno);
                int number = m.Groups[2];
```

You Can get last Four no or anything with grouping the regex.

If you only need last four-digit nothing more

```
      (.+)([0-9]{4}$)
```

use this and from a group[1](https://regex101.com/) you can get the last four no.

Comment: I sent the regex in the thread for all credit card formats.  I just want to get the last 4 digits.

Comment: if you do not care  what in front you only need last 4 charachters you can use this (.+)([0-9]{4}$)

Comment: but what if the card number is within text words?

Comment: @Roel check my pattern, the example is within a paragraph.

Comment: @Roel You say that the last four-digit can be text as well that your point. if in start it does not matter if it text, no or character

Comment: What substitution should I used if I want all of them to be replaced? $1 will only replaced the first one.

Comment: I'm trying using this: foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(creditCardNumber, lastFourDigits, options))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
                    result = Regex.Replace(creditCardNumber, mastercard.ToString(), m.Index.ToString());
                }

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pattern to match the last four digits of an American Express card number.

**Pattern**

```regex
3[47]\d{2}\s?\d{6}\s?\d(\d{4})
```

See the demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/5KLyJt/4).

*Edit: Per request in the discussion we had in the chat, here's a consolidated pattern based on the patterns of most major card networks that you provided (without any research on the specification myself):* [**consolidated pattern**](https://regex101.com/r/95LlZa/3)

**Sources**

- [Anatomy of a Credit Card: Cardholder Name, Number, Network and More](https://www.creditcardinsider.com/learn/anatomy-of-a-credit-card/)
- [ISO/IEC 7812-1:2017 - Identification cards — Identification of issuers — Part 1: Numbering system](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:std:iso-iec:7812:-1:ed-5:v1:en)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218415/discussion-between-bren-and-roel).

Comment: Do you have a sample syntax?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_